# Postgres...how to improve ilike results (quality not speed)

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a list of chemicals in my database and I provide our users with the ability to do a live search via our website.  I use SQLAlchemy and the query I use looks something like this:

```
Compound.query.filter(Compound.name.ilike(f'%{name}%')).limit(50).all()
```

When someone searches for **toluene**, for example, they don't get the result they're looking for because there are many chemicals that have the word toluene in them, such as:

- 2, 4 Dinitrotoluene
- 2-Chloroethyl-p-toluenesulfonate
- 4-Bromotoluene
- 6-Amino-m-toluenesulfonic acid
- a,2,4-trichlorotoluene
- a,o-Dichlorotoluene
- a-Bromtoluene
- etc...

I realize I could increase my `limit` but I feel like 50 is more than enough.  Or, I could change the `ilike(f'%{name}%'))` to something like `ilike(f'{name}%'))` but our business requirements don't want this.   What I'd rather do is improve the ability for Postgres to return results so that **toluene** is at the top of the search results.

Any ideas on how Postgres' ilike capability?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to better rank the results. [Postgres text search allows you to rank the results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING).

A cheap and dirty version of preferential ranking is to do multiple queries for `name = ?`, `ilike(f'{name}%'))`, and `ilike(f'%{name}%'))` using a [`union`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). That way the `ilike(f'{name}%'))` results come first.

And rather than a hard limit, offer pagination. SQLAlchemy has [`paginate`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate) to help.

Answer (score 0):

ILIKE yields a boolean.  It doesn't specify what order to return the results, just whether to return them at all (you can order by a boolean, but if you only return trues there is nothing left to order by).  So by the time you are done improving it, it would no longer be ILIKE at all but something else completely.

You might be looking for something like `<->` from [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html), which provides a distance score which can be sorted on.  Although really, you could just order the result based on the length of the compound name, and return the shortest 50 that contain the target.

> something like ilike(f'{name}%')) but our business requirements don't want this

Isn't your business requirement to get better results?

But at least in my database, this could just return a bunch of names in inverted format, like `toluene, 2,4-dinitro`, so the results might not be much better, unless you avoid storing such inverted names.  Sorting by either <-> or by length would overcome that problem.  But they would also penalize `toluene, ACS reagent grade 99.99% by HPLC`, should you have names like that.